# Java JAX-WS multiple web services for fail over configuration and architecture

Tags: java, swing, ejb, jax-ws, stateless

I have a java Swing application client and multiple glassfish servers with different names running copies of the same Stateless EJB JAX-WS for fail over.

First, is this a proper way to set up fail over and are there any resources available to help?

Secondly, the way I did it was to import all methods from the web services into seperate java classes then have a separate management class that calls each method.  Within each method call it determines the appropriate connection (i.e. if the web service call fails it increments to the next web service). The problem is this is a large amount of code that is difficult to maintain as it is not an efficient method.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, is this a proper way to set up fail over

I recommend to use an application server with clustering capabilities, e.g. GlassFish v3.1

http://glassfish.java.net/public/clustering31.html

Comment: clustering is a good idea, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you Puce.

Comment: This site explains the process for setting up clustering: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/abdaq.html#scrolltoc